# Remove role event with Discord JS

Tags: javascript, discord, bots

I am currently working on creating a Discord bot using [Discord.js](https://discord.js.org/#/). If someone removes a role of the guild, I want the bot to know **the ID of the removed role**. How do I do that? Do I have to use the [RoleManager](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/RoleManager)?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use event `guildMemberUpdate` for this. If somethink change for member, its will trigger it. So you need compare roles at the first, and then check removed roles by filter collection.

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const bot = new Discord.Client()

bot.on('guildMemberUpdate', (oldMember, newMember) => {
    const isRolesChanged = !oldMember.roles.cache.equals(newMember.roles.cache)
    if (!isRolesChanged) {
        return
    }
    
    const removedRoles = oldMember.roles.cache.filter(role => newMember.roles.cache.has(role.id))
    console.log(removedRoles)
    
})

bot.login('TOKENHERE')
```